# Are there Hooks for featured image popup?

Tags: hooks, post-thumbnails

EDIT for clarity: I know there's the option to hook into the "insert media" popup in the wp admin. using the media_upload_tabs filter.

However, is there a way to hook into the "featured media" uploader popup? Apparently, it's different and the hooks don't apply.

We use the single media uploader in our frontend by enqueuing the media manager scripts and triggering it via a button. But we want to add some more functionality to this uploader (specifically a tab that, when clicked, shows a new pane and allows the user to search a 3rd party image api for images to import).

Do you know how we can hook into the single media manager popup? I've searched high and low and can't find anything.

Comment: downvoted as there are two links here for a long text no one going to bother to read, the first one refers to something which is deprecated (for some value of the word) for few years. Please edit the question, and make it self contained and a little bit more details on what you specifically trying to do will not hurt.

Comment: @MarkKaplun You could have just commented vs downvoting. I would have changed it. The question itself is not invalid or out of scope.

Comment: Developers documentation for Media Library is practically non existant, and it is very complicated to work with beyond basic images handling. I have not seen one article on extending Media Library with new tabs and functions.

Comment: Brutal. I'll dig into it and whatever I find out, I'll share here.